# Should the tag ultraintelligent-machine be changed to superintelligence?

Tags: discussion, tags

I did some googling and "ultraintelligent machine" seems to derive from a 1965 I.J. Good article.

My feeling is that such a tag would largely refer to his work, and that superintelligence more current term, possibly favored for its compactness.

To clarify:

- Wiki search for superintelligence [leads to a page of that title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superintelligence)
- Wiki search for ultraintelligent machine [leads to I.J. Good page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._J._Good#Research_and_publications)

> Let an ultraintelligent machine be defined as a machine that can far surpass all the intellectual activities of any man however clever.
>   
> <sub>Good's definition ultraintelligent machine:</sub>

My thinking is we need ***both***, because Good is quite important, and ultra intelligent machine should refer largely to his work.

By contrast, superintelligence should be used to refer to the concept in general.

- From a practical standpoint, I suspect superintelligence is more widely used, and likely sought for as a tag.  One who doesn't know Good's work might not think to search for ultraintelligent machine.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with making this change.  As far as can tell, to a first approximation, nobody uses the term "ultra-intelligence".  "Super intelligence" or "Artificial super intelligence" are the terms I see.